# How to add an array attribute to the collection?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I have global array of type string in my code that am trying to add to my collection.

i manage to add normal global string to the collection this way

```
  previewImage: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
      return PIurl;
    }
  }
```

is it possible to do it with a global array? if no, what alternatives i can use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just asking for defining a field that is an array of strings with SimpleSchema, you can do it like this:

```
myArrayOfStringsField: {
  type: [String]
}
```

You can surround any of the valid [SimpleSchema types](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#schema-rules) in []'s to make them arrays of that type.

Comment: i tried your solution, it sets it successfully to array type but i can't assign it my global array -_-

Comment: Are you trying to set it using the autoValue function?  If so, console.log the global variable and see if autoValue can see it.